# DSM DDNS Custom Variables IPv6

Tags: ipv6, synology, dyndns

I can't figure out the naming rule for IPv6 in the DSM DDNS settings.

I want to set up a DDNS with my Strato account. The problem is that the Strato preset only allows IPv4 forwarding:
[image: DDNS configuration for Strato Preset]

But I need **only** IPv6.
So I figured I could simply create my own custom preset, but there seems to be no naming rule for IPv6. Only `__MYIP__`, which returns the IPv4.
[image: Naming rules for variables in DDNS customization]

I've checked the help and did some Google work but with no success.

On my router it works like this:

```
https://mydoma.in:myplaintextpw@dyndns.strato.com/nic/update?hostname=mydoma.in&myip=<ip6addr>
```

But I can't figure out the naming rule for IPv6 in the DSM DDNS settings.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'strato', but are you sure that IPv6 is supported on this system or by the service?

Comment: Strato definitely supports ipv6. the example https://mydoma.in:myplaintextpw@dyndns.strato.com/nic/update?hostname=mydoma.in&myip=<ip6addr> works with strato no problem (although I did not include my actual data in this example query). The problem here lies with the Synology NAS which does not seem to give me any option to include ipv6 or to create my own DDNS query URL with ipv6